# & > a in jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

How can I use the css(less) selector `& > a` inside a jQuery selector? Currently I have an jQuery object and want to search in it's direct children. Just skip the `&` also doesn't work.

```
var $e = $('...');
var $x = $('> a', $e); // don't work
```

**EDIT:**

I was wrong - the above worked and my error was somewhere else..

Answer (score 4):

Just try with [`.children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/):

```
$e.children('a')
```

Comment: And what about `a > span`?

Comment: You can still use any CSS selectors with `children`.

Answer (score 0):

`&` won't work that is less (and SASS) syntax that is transformed by the less (or SASS) pre-processor.

But you can use a different form of the jQuery function

```
$(selector, element)
```

which only considers the element and its descendants. If you want children only include something to select the current element in the selector

```
$('#startElementId > a', element)
```

Comment: If I use `$('a', $('#startElementId'))` this also looks for nested elements, which is not what I want

Comment: @Philipp I updated, if you want immediate children the selector needs to reflect that.